# How to make Xll stop working (if license is invalid)?

Tags: xll

So, if I want to write an Xll and license the code then I need a point at which to check the license file and if license is invalid then I want the Xll to stop working.

I see [xlAutoOpen](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb687860.aspx) looks like a good place to inspect the license file.  I also see that xlAutoOpen must return 1 according to the documentation, what happens if something other than 1 is returned?   Can I abort the Xll opening?  Can I force an unload?

Are there any better places to check the license and refuse to operate.  Surely, I don't have to wait until the first worksheet function invocation.

I am unfamiliar with this framework currently so forgive newbie-ness.

EDIT: I suppose I can refuse to call xlfRegister.  That will prevent operation.

EDIT2: From the Excel SDK Help file

> xlAutoAdd ...  can be used to  ... check licensing information, for example.

Also, found that on [MSDN xlAutoAdd](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb687898(v=office.15).aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check licensing information in `xlAutoOpen` since this function is the first entry point to activate the XLL and is **always** called by Excel. If password is invalid just returns 0 to indicates failure to excel **and** do not register your UDFs (quit before to call `xlfRegister`).

> I have noticed that if you register your UDFs and that you returns 0 ,
>   the xll is still loaded and UDFs are available, so the return
>   variable from  `xlAutoOpen` does not seem to be taken into account by
>   Excel but by convention I believe it is better to keep returning zero
>   to indicate failure.

I believe MSDN doc is misleading.
`xlAutoAdd` is not suitable to check license since it is an optional function that is called **only** when the XLL is added by the Add-In Manager or when it is opened as a document (using File/Open). I assume that you may have trial licence and so that you should check it at every load time if the user's licence is still valid.

---

**Example**

Usually, you call `xlAutoOpen` from `xlAutoAdd` so your check will still be done :
pseudo code :

```
  int __stdcall xlAutoAdd(void)
  { 

   if(!Isinitialised) 
       if( xlAutoOpen() == 0) // licence check is still performed
         returns 0 ;
        ...

       MessageBoxA(GetActiveWindow(), "Thank you to install ...", "AutoOpen", MB_OK);

   Isinitialised = true;
 }
```

since `xlAutoOpen` is always called by Excel you should perform a similar check inside it :

```
bool Isinitialised = false;
int __stdcall xlAutoOpen(void) // Register the functions
{

   if(Isinitialised)
      return 1;

   if(!ValidLicense()) // check licence in xlAutoOpen
      return 0;

    // continue initialization , registration ..

   .....
   Isinitialised = true;
  }
```

Finally note that you can omit `xlAutoAdd` because it has no adverse consequences and is not required by Excel. Personally I do not use this function.